# Change fragment by function

Tags: java, android

I got fragment based activity in android studio

```
                    someFragment fragment = new someFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentttTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                    fragmentttTransaction.commit();
```

I would like to invoke this by a function, something like that:

```
        public void gotofragment(String classname) {

    ...
}
```

I've tried to use Class.forName(classname).newInstance() but it didn't work, android studio shows errors.

Thanks for help in thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    private void showFragment(String fragmentId) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentId);
    if (fragment == null) {
        if (fragmentId.equals("Type1") {
            fragment = Type1Fragment.newInstance();
        }else if (fragmentId.equals("Type2") {
            fragment = Type2Fragment.newInstance();
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentId).commit();
    }
}
```